# Can I set the number of worker processes in app.json?

Tags: heroku

I’ve written a Node application that only uses a worker process, no web process. The [Deploy to Heroku button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) is working to deploy the application: I set the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable to 0 to disable the web process, but my naïve use of a `WORKER_CONCURRENCY` variable didn’t set the number of worker processes.

I know I can just require that people run `heroku ps:scale worker=1` to create the worker processes, but I’d love if I could avoid that extra configuration step.

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32697027 It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this via the "formations" setting in your app.json, described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#formation

Although their example only shows web, I have tested that it works with other formation names too (e.g. as defined in your Procfile).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got an app to deploy with only a worker using the formations in app.json:

```
{
  ...,
  "formation": {
    "web": {
      "quantity": 0,
      "size": "free"
    },
    "worker": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "free"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to Heroku support and they said:

> I'm afraid there is no way to achieve this at the moment.

Harsh!