# Use N web dynos and M worker dynos on Heroku review app

Tags: heroku

I am currently using Heroku's Review apps feature and it is great.
The only issue is that at the moment, when a new app is created from a pull request, it only has 1 web Dyno and 0 workers. My app requires a couple of web Dynos and workers, hence I need to manually edit those in my dashboard.
Is there a way (e.g. through the `app.json` config) to specify the number of Dynos used and their type when a new Review app is created?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: this is now officially supported**

Try adding something like this to your `app.json`

```
"formation": {
      "web": { 
          "quantity": 1
      },
      "worker": { 
          "quantity": 1
      }
},
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#formation

Comment: This is now officially supported, with a slightly different serialization: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#formation.